# Why is Steam trying to load up games with optional parameters?

Tags: steam, borderlands-2, garrys-mod

I am trying to join my friend's Garry's Mod server and Steam is telling me that Garry's Mod is trying to launch with optional parameters. I don't know why, and he is telling me that he does not know.

The code it is trying to run is:

```
+connect p2p:(a long string of numbers is here).
```

What does this mean exactly? Should I be concerned? As of now, I have not connected yet.

Update: I tried to join a friend's Borderlands 2 game and it gave me a similar thing.

It tried to run:

```
+connect_lobby (a long string of numbers)
```

Is Steam just displaying something it normally doesn't?

Update: It has stopped loading them up with optional parameters, or at least showing me that it has been.

Comment: Does this only appear after you click on a friend's invite to join a server or you click to join a friend? I havea a feeling it's steam's mechanism of telling the game which server to join upon launching the game

Comment: @Draken in the GMOD instance I tried to join through the PM tab I had with them, while on the BL2 instance I tried to accept an invite that they sent me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Perfectly normal.**

The game has to know somehow that you intend to join your friend. Thats what the parameters are for, those allow you to be connect to the same multi-player session.

Comment: It's not normal such a message should appear though, normally that message should be hidden and not visible to the user. I'm curoious on why they are now being warned about this

Comment: @Draken i cant check since i am at work but i believe there is an option in the Settings froM Steam to notify about that. Maybe they added this also as an security feature.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the [SteamAPI documentation](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/api/ISteamMatchmaking), this does appear to be normal:

> If the user outside a game chooses to join, your game will be launched with the parameter +connect_lobby <64-bit lobby id>, or with the callback GameLobbyJoinRequested_t if they're already in-game.

I can't find anything in the documentation for `+connect p2p`, but I'm sure its something along the same lines as the other optional parameter you've seen.

Comment: But why is steam warning that it's launching with these optional parameters? I've joined many a friend's game on Steam via invite and following them through their profile and never been warned. It's odd that steam is warning this. Is this a new update, has the OP turned a flag on by accident?

Comment: Note: These are parameters being passed to the game executable, so they don't have to be the same for every game.